Using QRcode, in some unknown cases, QRcode doesn't generate a fit qr image
I am trying to generate QRcode with "qrcode".
I am able to do it, but in some unknown cases, it generates code that cannot be shown and present like it cannot be loaded.
For example, when I write "arad", it generates qr code, but when I add "1", it does not.
It also is not working if I enter numbers only, or just one letter.
I couldn't understand the exact cases which it's not working.


This is my client API to the backend:
import { Body, Controller, Get, Param, Put } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

let qr;

@Controller("/users")
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return qr;
  }

  @Put(":id")
  restaurantQRCdoe(@Param('id') id: string, @Body('img') qrCode: string) {
    qr = qrCode;
  }
}

and this is my client api to backend:
import axios from "axios";

const baseBackendURL = `http://localhost:5006/users/`;
export class UsersHttp{

    static async postNewRestaurantQRCode(qrCode: string) {
        axios({
            method: 'put',
            url: baseBackendURL + "arad11",
            data: {
                img: qrCode + "asf"
            }
        })
    }

    static async getQR(){
        return await axios({
            url: baseBackendURL,
            method: 'get',
        });
    }
}

This is my client component:
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {UsersHttp} from "../usersHttp/users";
import QRcode from "qrcode";

export function Restaurant () {
    const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
    const [src, setSrc] = useState("");
    const [qr, setqr] = useState();

    const qrGenerator = useCallback(() => {
        QRcode.toDataURL(`https://github.com/${username}`).then((setSrc));
    },[username]);
    
    const sendToBackend = useCallback(async () => {
        await UsersHttp.postNewRestaurantQRCode(src.toString());
    },[src]);

    const getQRFromBackend = useCallback(async () => { 
         const res = (await UsersHttp.getQR()).data;
         setqr(res);
    },[]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("arad", qr);
    },[qr]);

    return(
        <>
            <input
                placeholder="insert restaurant name"
                value={username}
                onChange={(text) => setUserName(text.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="submit" onClick={qrGenerator}>click here</button>
            <img src={qr}></img>
            <button type="submit" onClick={sendToBackend}>click</button>
            <button type="submit" onClick={getQRFromBackend}>click get qr code</button>
            

        </>
    )
}


"it generates code that cannot be shown" - what does that mean? Can you check your server for error messages? Maybe the response itself already contains some details?

my server shows no errors. 
Moreover, when I print it to dev-tools console, I can see that it looks just fine. 
It generate some "data:image/png;base64,.........." some img. but when I try to have qr for chars and numbers it says error. the error says:
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIQAAACECAYAAABRRIOnAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAABqhJREFUeF7tncuW2zAMQyf//9HTTRe..............
GET net::ERR_INVALID_URL

I change nothing between generate qr for chars or numbers

Now I see, if I use the image directly through the client, it works well. but when I get it by the http Get request I get the error. It is probably parsing not good.

What do you mean by "I get the error"? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section
